# Why is the difference of two vectors parallel to the vector connecting the two vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, intuition

Say we have any two vectors $u$ and $v$. We want to find a vector $w$ that is parallel to the vector that goes from $u$ to $v$ (is there a standard notation for this vector?). Then I already know that such a vector can be found simply by subtracting one of the two vectors from the other. Can you give me some intuition why this works? Probably what I am not understanding is how you get the vector connecting $u$ and $v$ in the first place.

Comment: Because $v=u+(v-u)$?

Comment: The vector $w$ connecting $u$ to $v$ is the vector satisfying $v=u+w$. Because that's what it means to add vectors, really. Now subtracting $u$ yields $w$. So the difference is not just parallel to the connecting vector, it *is* the connecting vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there's already an accepted answer, I'd like to add some visual intuition to the ideas. In particular, I want to address the OP's sentence:

> the vector that goes from $u$ to $v$

[image: vector additions]

A very important aspect of vector spaces is that all vectors "start" from the origin. There is no such thing as a vector starting from the tip of another vector. What I have pictured in orange are **not** vectors, there are only helpful to get an intuition for vector addition. The "real" $u$, $v$ and $w$ vectors are in black, and sure, it's easy to understand $u+w=v$ if you follow the path (black $u$, orange $w$), but that doesn't mean that the orange $w$ is a member of the vector space. Same thing with $w=v-u$, which is $w=v+(-u)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can vectors have a position though?

Comment: Once a basis has been selected, say $(i,j)$ if we stay in the plane, with $i$ and $j$ linearly independent, then you can always find scalars $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that any vector $u$ can be expressed as $u=\alpha i + \beta j$. This allows you to identify $u$ with the tuple $( \alpha, \beta )$. In that sense, vectors have a "position", I guess. I'm not sure about terminology (I'm not a native English speaker), but I believe it's more common to call this tuple 'coordinates' (which are relative to a specific basis)

Comment: Exercise: say we choose $(u,w)$ as a basis in my diagram above. Then $u$ has coordinates $(1,0)$, and w has coordinates $(0,1)$. What are the coordinates of $v$ and $-u$?

Answer (score 1):

It's a consequence of how vector addition works. Say we're traveling along $v$ then going to $u$ and to get there I travel along some other vector $x$. Geometrically we would model this as $v+x=u$ and then solving for $x$ gives us $x=u-v$. Now it becomes $v + (u-v)=u$ and we see this works both algebraically and geometrically.